# Angular 6 telephone number with call option

Tags: angular, html

In angularJs, you can bind a telephone number to your HTML with the HTML5 feature to click it to trigger calling the number, as follows:

```
<a href="tel:{{location.phoneNumber}}">{{location.phoneNumber | phoneFilter}}</a>
```

How do you do this in Angular 6? I tried the following but it throws me an error:

```
<a [href]="tel:{{l.phoneNumber}}">{{l.phoneNumber}}</a>
```

Comment: are you using IONIC ?

Comment: No, I don't use ICONIC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it the same way in Angular with the template binding syntax `{{...}}` or by using string concatenation when using the attribute binding `[href]="..."`. Examples:

```
<a href="tel:{{location.phoneNumber}}">{{location.phoneNumber | phoneFilter}}</a>
<a [href]="'tel:' + location.phoneNumber">{{location.phoneNumber | phoneFilter}}</a>
```

### [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tuawjp)

Answer (score 1):

Try change it to:

```
<a href={{'tel:'+l.phoneNumber}}>{{l.phoneNumber}}</a>
```